# How to find the maximum flow in a multi source flow network?

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

[image: In this image there is a multi source flow network]

How to convert this multi source flow network in to single source flow network and find the maximum flow in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a dummy source node, called `Source`, and draw a directed edge of close-to-infinite-capacity (e.g. sum of capacities of all edges of the graph) from `Source` to each tank. Every flow in the resulting graph is in one-to-one correspondence with the original multi-source graph.